# Excel naming dynamic variable

Tags: excel, variables, excel-formula

I'm creating an excel sheet which takes a sum of variables based on value of A,B,C and the number along with it 10A,20B, or 9C So,

```
10A = 10, 20B = 40, 9C = 27
```

to put it in simple terms

`A=1, B=2, C=3`

```
10A = 10(1); 20B = 20(2); 9C = 9(3);
```

Is that possible to do in Excel 2016?

Comment: Have you tried using Name Manager to setup your variables and then multiplying the number times the defined name?

Comment: Yes i have tried that but it's not possible to do in this case to my knowledge . I can assign value to A but when i will use 10A it will not multiply. It will work if i use it in the formula of the sum and just type 10 instead of 10A in Row.
`=SUM(B1:I1)*A` 

But what if i have 10A and 20B in same Row than it wont work with
`=SUM(B1:I1)*A`

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Excel needs to know your operator (`*` in this case). Otherwise it's going to interpret things like `10A` as a string (i.e. text), not a numerical value with a variable. In other words, no, I don't think what you're hoping to do is possible.

Comment: Thank you @TotsieMae for taking a look into my problem.

Comment: You're welcome, Khan. And welcome to the site! If you happen upon a solution to your issue above, please come back and update your question so future visitors are able to benefit from your knowledge.

Comment: Sure thing TotsieMae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*(CODE(RIGHT(A1))-64)
```

(If to be added up: `{=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:C1,LEN(A1:C1)-1)*(CODE(RIGHT(A1:C1))-64))}`)

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this???? It worked perfectly just as required. I can't thank you enough for this. It really solved a huge problem i was facing for a week.
Thank you pnuts you're my new favorite person.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table with your values. In my example, I called TB_VALUES

[image]

Then you can combine your table with a VLOOKUP to search for a letter and make the operation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing a detail answer. But it wont work as per my requirements. Since integer and Character are suppose to be in same cell. I tried to use this method followed by `OFFSET()` to jump between columns and take sum of only the numbers but it was just keep getting more and more complex. When i had to multiply value of A, B or C.
Thanks again.